# Parsing parameters onclick for angularjs app

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, onclick, angularjs-scope

I am working on enhancing a feature of an already deployed application. All the js code is minified and i only can excess html files. I need to call a function on-click of a 'div' which parse some elements and open a new tab with resolved url(url updated with help of parsed elements).

My initial thought is to make a function in a new js file and add link to it on main html page. Evidently the call to function is fine with on click attribute call on the div. But while passing the angular controller parameters it throws error -

```
<div onclick="jumpToPage({{vm.username}})"></div>

function jumpToPage(user){
    console.log(user);
};
```

Note - I don't have access to update minified files and i know i can un-minified it but there are lot of files and process is too long.

Please let me know how to resolve/pass parameter to JavaScript function

Comment: `jumpToPage()` is function in angular controller or javascript ?

Comment: it not angular controller, its a function in js file

Answer (score 0):

It should be `onclick="jumpToPage(vm.username)">`

If you pass `{{vm.username}}` it will get evaluted.

e.g. `vm.username ="some_name"`

so,your controller will get `some_name` and not referance to `vm.username` 
and

it try to search for the same refarance.If it not find then throw exception.

Comment: I am not calling this function in angular controller. So when i pass vm.username it throws exception. vm not found

Comment: Can u share the html for controller directive

Comment: I do not have controller for this function, it is outside angular scope

Answer (score 0):

try to use ng-click, when we use ng-click we don't need to use {{}} anymore, since it is automatically bind the model.

Comment: can't use ng-click, as i dnt have access to controller. THis function is a plain js file function outside angular scope